# Allowing only one connection among multiple openvpn servers

Tags: linux, openvpn

Just wondering it's possible to allow only one connection among multiple openvpn servers?

For example, if I have 3 openvpn servers like below, I want the client to connect only one of the servers among 3.

It looks 3 openvpn servers share some information. Is it possible?

server1.conf

```
server 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun
proto tcp
port PORT
keepalive 10 120
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"

ca cacert.pem
cert server1.crt
key server1.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

server2.conf

```
server 10.0.110.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun
proto tcp
port PORT
keepalive 10 120
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"

ca cacert.pem
cert server2.crt
key server2.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

server3.conf

```
server 10.0.50.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun
proto tcp
port PORT
keepalive 10 120
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"

ca cacert.pem
cert server3.crt
key server3.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

Anyone has an idea about this?

Comment: g'day - i think this q would be better answered at one of the server or network admin config stacks, in any case, details on your host operating system/ environment will be helpful

Comment: You need a shared "database" where each of the openvpn servers  checks (`client-connect <scriptname>`)  if the limit of concurrent sessions has been reached  and then either reject or register the start of the new connection.   At the  end of a session  (`client-disconnect <scriptname>`) records that the session has ended. https://serverfault.com/q/850599/37681